# Error installing pandoc

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pandoc

I'm using windows 7. The purpose is to get nbconvert working. I have the latest ipython version 3.1.0, or jupyter.

```
C:\Users\yang>pip install pandoc

Collecting pandoc
 Using cached pandoc-1.0.0a8.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "c:\users\yang\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-_lwwnn\pandoc\setup.py",
line 27, in <module>
    import about
  File "c:\users\yang\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-_lwwnn\pandoc\.lib\about\
__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    import sh
  File "c:\users\yang\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-_lwwnn\pandoc\.lib\sh.py"
, line 37, in <module>
    support." % __version__)
ImportError: sh 1.11 is currently only supported on linux and osx. please in
stall pbs 0.110 (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbs) for windows support.

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\yang
\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-_lwwnn\pandoc
```

I installed pbs successfully, but did not resolve this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`pandoc` is not a Python package. Try installing the latest release from [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases). Here's a [direct link](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/download/1.13.2/pandoc-1.13.2-windows.msi).

Answer (score 0):

The `pandoc` package requires the `sh` package. This results in `sh` 1.11 getting installed. `sh` is apparently [the successor to `pbs`](https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/master/README.md) but [no longer supports Windows](https://github.com/amoffat/sh/issues/231).

So unfortunately the `pandoc` package also does not appear to support Windows as it tries to import `sh`, not `pbs`. You could consider reporting an issue. Perhaps in the mean while you could use [`pypandoc`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypandoc) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use:

```
pip install pypandoc
```